# Convertir 'n' número de filas en columnas en SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

les cuento mi necesidad. Tengo la siguiente tabla en SQL, necesito convertir a columnas todas las filas de *Concepto* que tengan Monto mayor a cero. No tengo un número específico de *Conceptos* pueden ser N cantidad.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado que espero obtener es este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si observan lo que ocupo es que la información se agrupe por ejercicio y periodo, si algún Concepto está en ceros para todos los empleados no debe mostrarse. Además deben ordenarse de izquierda a derecha primero las percepciones, deducciones y obligaciones (Por eso agregué las columnas de *Tipo* y *Orden* para identificarlos.) Al final debo adaptar la consulta a un store procedure o a una vista.

Este es el código con el que estoy trabajando. Ya convierte N filas  de Concepto a columnas y agrega el Monto donde debe ir pero no encuentro la forma de que me los ordene por Tipo o por el número que puse en **Orden**. Otro detalle que tengo es que si un Concepto está en cero en todos los empleados lo sigue mostrando.

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @query NVARCHAR(MAX);

 --Aquí convierto las filas de Concepto en columnas.
 SET @cols = STUFF(
             (
                 SELECT DISTINCT
                        ','+QUOTENAME(c.[Concepto])
                 FROM [dbo].[TablaConcentrado] c where (c.[Monto]>0) FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
             ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');

  --Aquí uno con el resto de los campos, ya no pongo los campos Tipo y Orden porque no me interesa 
   --mostrarlos.

 SET @query = 'SELECT DISTINCT Año,Semana,IDEmpleado,'+@cols+'from (SELECT
       [Año],[Semana],[ID],[Concepto] as categoria,[Monto] as amount
 FROM [dbo].[TablaConcentrado] WHERE  ejercicio = 2020 AND (importetotal > 0)  

 )x pivot (max(amount) for categoria in ('+@cols+')) p';
  EXECUTE (@query);
```

Agradecería sus sugerencias para poder adaptarlo. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la obtención de las columnas justo antes de FOR XML PATH, puedes utilizar un order by.

Aunque en tú ejemplo hay cosas que a priori, quizá no estén detalladas, pues no se ve porque préstamo va antes que seguro.

Te expongo una manera de realizarlo.

```
create table TablaConcentrado (Año int, Semana int, IdEmpleado int, Concepto varchar(100), Monto int, Tipo char(1), Orden int)
go
insert into TablaConcentrado (año, Semana, IdEmpleado, Concepto, Monto, Tipo, Orden)
values
(2020,24,1,'Sueldo'  ,100,'P',1),
(2020,24,1,'Préstamo', 50,'D',2),
(2020,24,2,'Sueldo'  ,150,'P',1),
(2020,24,2,'Seguro'  , 20,'D',2),
(2020,25,1,'Sueldo'  ,100,'P',1),
(2020,25,1,'Bono',     70,'P',1),
(2020,25,1,'Préstamo', 50,'D',2),
(2020,25,1,'Impuesto', 10,'D',3),
(2020,25,2,'Sueldo',    NULL,'P',1);
go

declare @cols nvarchar(max),@query nvarchar(max);
-- Para añadir restricciones al pivot
Declare @ColsWhere Nvarchar(max);

Declare @colsTable table (id int identity(1,1), concepto nvarchar(100), orden int); 

Insert into @colsTable (concepto, orden)
    select top(100) percent concepto, orden from
        (select concepto, orden from [dbo].[TablaConcentrado] c where (c.[Monto]>0) group by concepto, orden) c
order by orden, concepto desc


 --Aquí convierto las filas de Concepto en columnas.
 SET @cols = STUFF(
             (
                 SELECT 
                        ','+QUOTENAME(c.[Concepto])
                 FROM @colsTable c
                 order by id FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '');

-- Añadimos un IS NOT NULL para todas las columnas

set @COLSWhere = CONCAT('WHERE ',(replace(@cols ,',',' IS NOT NULL OR ')),' IS NOT NULL')
  --Aquí uno con el resto de los campos, ya no pongo los campos Tipo y Orden porque no me interesa 
   --mostrarlos.

 SET @query = CONCAT(N'SELECT Año,Semana,IDEmpleado,'+@cols+' from (SELECT
                [Año],[Semana],[IDEmpleado],[Concepto] as categoria,[Monto] as amount
            FROM [dbo].[TablaConcentrado]
  )as Source
 pivot (max(amount) for categoria in ('+@cols+')) p
 ',@ColsWhere);
  exec (@query);
```

Te he quitado algunos distinct porque sobran y la obtención del orden de las columnas, la he metido dentro de una variable tipo tabla (probablemente redundante), pero te sirve para ajustar los criterios de ordenamiento que necesites. También algún pequeño ajuste de columnas, ya que no tenía where ejercicio.

Al final quien marca el orden en el que se muestran las columnas es @COLS.

[image: Resultados sin NULL]

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta @Javifer2 me ha funcionado bastante bien y ahora me queda claro qué ajustes eran necesarios. En mi información se siguen mostrando conceptos aunque en toda la columna esté como null pero de momento ese detalle lo solucionaré desde la interface. De nuevo gracias.

Comment: Entonces tienes entradas con valores null. Esto lo puedes eliminar en añadiendo una restricción. En unos minutos, modifico el código, para que puedas agregar restricciones al pivot.

Comment: @Javifer2 una duda que siempre he tenido es porque se coloca la N al inicio en algunos casos con SQL Server?

Comment: Añado una respuesta más para solucionar esta pequeña duda.

Answer (score 1):

> una duda que siempre he tenido es porque se coloca la N al inicio en algunos casos con SQL Server?

```
declare @a varchar(100)  = '中华人民共和国';
declare @b nvarchar(100) = '中华人民共和国';
declare @c nvarchar(100) = N'中华人民共和国';

SELECT @A, @B, @C
```

La N sirve para indicarle al motor que el contenido es UNICODE.

[image: Resultado]

Normalmente para la ejecución de querys dinámicas se utiliza exec sp_executeSql con un parámetro de tipo NVarchar donde esta la query porque entre otras cosas, permite mediante parámetros evitar la inyección de código sql.

Si observas la definición de sp_executesql en sus argumentos @stmt = (instrucción), nos indica que espera una cadena Unicode.

Eso solucionaría, el @query, pero además el @cols y @colsWhere tienen la misma particularidad. Quiero decirte con esto, que es una query dinámica, por tanto se desconoce a priori el nombre de las columnas, y si @cols es un nVarchar el mismo código vale para nosotros, que para un desarrollo de Japón.

[sp_executeSql](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Sos un crack @Javifer2

Comment: @Javifer2 ¿Cómo quedaría convertido a procedimiento almacenado la consulta que está dentro de SET @query?

Comment: Expón una nueva pregunta con un enlace a esta, para poder responderte, con código, A priori, por lo que pareces indicar, sería bastante con recibir dos parámetros cols y colsWhere, y que estos datos se le inyectasen al mismo.

Comment: Gracias @Javifer2, ya la expuse, agradecería mucho tus sugerencias. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/366580/adaptar-consulta-con-variables-a-consulta-con-vistas-y-store-procedure

Comment: @Jonsin Ya te he publicado una respuesta para que puedas ir ajustando el código.

Comment: Mil gracias @Javifer2