# Adaptar consulta con variables a consulta con vistas y store procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

[https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/365745/convertir-n-n%c3%bamero-de-filas-en-columnas-en-sql/367271#367271](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/365745/convertir-n-n%C3%BAmero-de-filas-en-columnas-en-sql/367271#367271) Me atoré en el último paso de mi consulta. Tengo el siguiente código que funciona perfectamente para mis necesidades (En el enlace está publicada la pregunta donde me apoyaron a darle forma) traspone filas en columnas, más sin embargo está adaptado a modo de variables. Necesito cambiarlo a vistas y procedimientos almacenados para que me sea más práctico disponer de él a través del código de la aplicación que desarrollaré. Agradecería su ayuda.

Donde tengo problema es en el último SP llamado **resultado**, no logro adaptarlo de forma correcta y al ejecutarlo me manda mensajes como:

```
Mens. 207, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 2
El nombre de columna 'ad1.descripcion' no es válido.
Mens. 207, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 2
El nombre de columna 'ad1.importetotal' no es válido.
```

Este es mi código con variables (Funciona bien):

```
Declare @colsTable table (id int identity(1,1), descripcion nvarchar(100), numconcepto int) 

Insert into @colsTable (descripcion, numconcepto) 

select top(100) percent descripcion, numconcepto from
(select descripcion, numconcepto from [dbo].[tbConcentrado] c where (c.[importetotal]>0) and (c. 
[idperiodo]=772) group by descripcion, numconcepto) c


SET @cols = STUFF(
         (
             SELECT 
                    ','+QUOTENAME(c.[descripcion])
             FROM @colsTable c
             order by id FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '');

SET @query = 'SELECT ejercicio,idperiodo,numeroperiodo,'+@cols+' from (SELECT
            ejercicio,idperiodo,numeroperiodo,[descripcion] as categoria,[importetotal] as amount
        FROM [dbo].[tbConcentrado] WHERE  ejercicio = 2020  and idperiodo = 772
  )as Source
 pivot (max(amount) for categoria in ('+@cols+')) p';
  exec (@query);
```

Este es el que estoy adaptando y donde tengo el error:

```
Create Table colsTable(
id int identity(1,1),
descripcion nvarchar(100),
numconcepto int
) 

create proc ADC_colsTable(
@idperiodo int
)
as insert into colsTable (descripcion,numconcepto)
select top(100) percent descripcion, numconcepto from
(select descripcion, numconcepto from [dbo].[tbConcentrado] c where (c.[importetotal]>0) and (c. 
[idperiodo]=@idperiodo) group by descripcion, numconcepto) c
order by numconcepto,descripcion desc
go

create view colsTableV as   
SELECT  
 STUFF(
    (
     SELECT 
            ','+QUOTENAME(c.[descripcion]) 
             FROM colsTable c
             order by id FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as descripcion;

--A partir de aquí me atoré 
  
create proc resultado
@idperiodo
as
SELECT ad1.ejercicio,ad1.idperiodo,ad1.numeroperiodo,'+ct.descripcion+' from (SELECT
ad1.ejercicio,ad1.idperiodo,ad1.numeroperiodo,ad1.descripcion as categoria, 
ad1.importetotal as amount
        FROM [dbo].[tbConcentrado] ad1 inner join colsTableV ct on ad1.descripcion=ct.descripcion 
WHERE idperiodo = @idperiodo
 )as Source
 pivot (max(amount) for categoria in ('+ct.descripcion+')) p;
```

Comment: Saludos. Prueba quitar los corchetes a `[ad1.descripcion] as categoria, 
[ad1.importetotal] as amount`en el `SELECT`.

Comment: Gracias por responder @RobertoLeOr. Ya los quité y ya no marca errores pero al ejecutar no muestra información la consulta. Me queda duda la última línea, donde dice pivot, no sé si estoy haciendo referencia correctamente al campo descripcion de la tabla colsTableV.

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. El `'+ct.descripcion+'` que tienes en el `SELECT`y en el `PIVOT`¿Estan así en código u olvidaste darle la forma por los valores que se usan?; así mismo, al final del `PIVOT`hay un símbolo despues de `p`y antes del punto y coma.

Comment: Están así en código, si te fijas de esa manera los concatené desde el primer código que generé con variables. Excepto el símbolo después de p y antes del ; ese ya lo quité, no debe ir.

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. El `PIVOT`no lo he usado; el `'+ct.descripcion+'`que te menciono como tal es texto; no me parece sea una referencia al campo `descripcion` de la tabla al que corresponde el alias `ct`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un poco de lío en los nombres de las columnas o al menos a mi me lo parece, con el enlace anterior. No obstante he cambiado la tabla tbConcentrado para que tenga las mismas columnas con la denominación que has puesto en este ticket. Aunque los datos de inserción no tengan ningún "sentido".

```
Create Table colsTable(
id int identity(1,1),
descripcion nvarchar(100),
numconcepto int
) 

create table [tbConcentrado] (NumeroPeriodo int, Ejercicio int, IdEmpleado int, descripcion varchar(100), ImporteTotal int, Tipo char(1), NumConcepto int, idPeriodo int)
go
insert into [tbConcentrado] (NumeroPeriodo, Ejercicio, IdEmpleado, descripcion, ImporteTotal, Tipo, NumConcepto, idPeriodo )
values
(2020,24,1,'Sueldo'  ,100,'P',1,24),
(2020,24,1,'Préstamo', 50,'D',2,24),
(2020,24,2,'Sueldo'  ,150,'P',1,24),
(2020,24,2,'Seguro'  , 20,'D',2,24),
(2020,25,1,'Sueldo'  ,100,'P',1,24),
(2020,25,1,'Bono',     70,'P',1,24),
(2020,25,1,'Préstamo', 50,'D',2,24),
(2020,25,1,'Impuesto', 10,'D',3,24),
(2020,25,2,'Sueldo',    NULL,'P',1,24);
GO
```

Ahora viene un poco el lío. Salvo que sean diferentes columnas, pero como no has puesto la definición de la tabla, a mi no me encaja.

```
create proc ADC_colsTable(
@idperiodo int
)
as 
insert into colsTable (descripcion,numconcepto)

select top(100) percent descripcion, numconcepto from
(select descripcion, numconcepto from [dbo].[tbConcentrado] c where (c.monto>0) and (c.[idperiodo]=@idperiodo) group by descripcion, numconcepto)
c
order by numconcepto,descripcion desc
go
```

Sobre este proc, varias cosas.

- ¿Para qué usar el operador top?
- ¿Para qué usar una tabla derivada?

Una vuelta de tuerca puede ser:

```
create proc ADC_colsTable_v2(
@IDPERIODO int)
as
BEGIN
insert into colsTable(descripcion, numconcepto)
    select descripcion, numconcepto
        from dbo.tbConcentrado 
    where ImporteTotal>0 and idperiodo=@IDPERIODO 
    group by descripcion, numconcepto
    order by numconcepto, descripcion desc;
END;
go
```

Ahora ejecutamos el proc para que tenga datos en la tabla colsTable

```
exec ADC_colsTable_v2 24
```

Creamos la vista.

```
Create View dbo.colsTableV as   
SELECT  
 STUFF(
    (
     SELECT 
            ','+QUOTENAME(c.[descripcion]) 
             FROM colsTable c
             order by id FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as descripcion;

GO
```

Verificamos que la vista obtiene lo que queremos.

```
select * from dbo.colsTableV
```

[image: Resultado de la vista]

Ahora modificamos el procedimiento resultado, ya que necesita ejecutar si o si una query dinámica para construir el pivot. Por tanto las columnas que salen de la vista las ponemos en una variable. El parámetro lo cambiamos a un tipo válido para la query, y las columnas que retorna el conjunto pivotado, no son del conjunto ad1, sino que ya pertenecen al conjunto pivot alias p. Por tanto las referencias son p.

```
create OR ALTER proc resultado 
@IDPERIODO int
as
begin
declare @IDPER varchar(100);
Set @IDPER=Cast(@IDPERIODO as varchar(100));
Declare @COLUMNAS nvarchar(max)=(Select descripcion from colsTableV);


Declare @QUERY nvarchar(max);
set @QUERY=N'SELECT p.ejercicio,p.idperiodo,p.numeroperiodo,'+@COLUMNAS+' from (SELECT
                ad1.ejercicio,ad1.idperiodo,ad1.numeroperiodo,ad1.descripcion as categoria, 
                ad1.importetotal as amount
        FROM [dbo].[tbConcentrado] ad1 
WHERE ad1.idperiodo = '+@IDPER+'
 )as Source
 pivot (max(amount) for categoria in ('+@COLUMNAS+')) p;';


EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @QUERY;

end;
```

Ahora con el mismo, realizamos la ejecución.

```
EXEC resultado 24
```

[image: Resultado]

Si te preocupa la seguridad de la ejecución de sp_executeSql, puedes incluir los parámetros como parte de la ejecución.

[exec sp_executeSql](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Mil gracias @Javifer2 ya me ha quedado clarísimo, las columnas están diferentes a la primer pregunta porque luego yo las adapté al entorno real, luego no las plasmé como en el primer ejemplo.